# is it possible to create interface from array like ["foo","far"] in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have tried

```js
const arr=["foo", "bar"]
type lol={
[key in arr]:string
}
```

I have tried many things but wont get expected answer, I dont think this is possible.
Expected output an interface with keys which arr have, is that possible with values
How can I make anything like it?
This is what typescript is saying

```js
A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20965

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way you can achieve your goal:

[Typescript playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m027Dw)

```ts
const arr = ["foo", "bar"] as const;

type lol = {
  [k in typeof arr[number]]: string;
};

/** returns
type lol = {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Referenced: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20965

```
const arr = ["foo", "bar"] as const;

type TestType = {
  [k in typeof arr[number]]: string;
};

const test: TestType = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'};
```